# How to attach the pdf file in the custom post type in the WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, pdf, post, custom-post-type

I am using WordPress. I have created a custom post type. Now I have to add the file upload option so that the admin can upload the pdf.

I have tried some code and I am getting the output and it's correct.

[image]

Now, My issue is when I upload the pdf and click on the publish button then it's not uploading. I am not getting any errors. I am using the below code.

```
function add_pdfcustom_meta_boxes() {  
    add_meta_box('wp_custom_attachment', 'Guideline Pdf Upload', 'wp_custom_attachment', 'guideline', 'normal', 'default');  
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_pdfcustom_meta_boxes');  

function wp_custom_attachment() {  
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'wp_custom_attachment_nonce');
    $html = '<p class="description">';
    // $html .= 'Upload your PDF here.';
    $html .= '</p>';
    $html .= '<input type="file" id="wp_custom_attachment" name="wp_custom_attachment" value="" size="25">';
    echo $html;
}

function save_pdfcustom_meta_data($id) {
     /* --- security verification --- */
    if(!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['wp_custom_attachment_nonce'], plugin_basename(__FILE__))) {
      return $id;
    } // end if
    if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
      return $id;
    } // end if
     if('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
      if(!current_user_can('edit_page', $id)) {
        return $id;
      } // end if
    } else {
        if(!current_user_can('edit_page', $id)) {
            return $id;
        } // end if
    }
   /* - end security verification - */
// Make sure the file array isn't empty
    if(!empty($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['name'])) {
         
        // Setup the array of supported file types. In this case, it's just PDF.
        $supported_types = array('application/pdf');
         
        // Get the file type of the upload
        $arr_file_type = wp_check_filetype(basename($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['name']));
        $uploaded_type = $arr_file_type['type'];
         
        // Check if the type is supported. If not, throw an error.
        if(in_array($uploaded_type, $supported_types)) {
 
            // Use the WordPress API to upload the file
            $upload = wp_upload_bits($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['name'], null, file_get_contents($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['tmp_name']));
     
            if(isset($upload['error']) && $upload['error'] != 0) {
                wp_die('There was an error uploading your file. The error is: ' . $upload['error']);
            } else {
                add_post_meta($id, 'wp_custom_attachment', $upload);
                update_post_meta($id, 'wp_custom_attachment', $upload);     
            } // end if/else
 
        } else {
            wp_die("The file type that you've uploaded is not a PDF.");
        } // end if/else
         
    } // end if


 
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_pdfcustom_meta_data');

function update_edit_form() {
    echo ' enctype="multipart/form-data"';
} // end update_edit_form
add_action('post_edit_form_tag', 'update_edit_form');
```

I am trying from this [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/attaching-files-to-your-posts-using-wordpress-custom-meta-boxes-part-1--wp-22291) and this [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103717/attach-pdf-file-to-custom-post-type)

Comment: The code is working. In your function wp_custom_attachment you can check if post have someting attached and show it above choose file button for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see if there is attached file to your post edit the following function

```
function wp_custom_attachment() {
 
    wp_nonce_field(plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'wp_custom_attachment_nonce');
    $file = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wp_custom_attachment', true); 
    if($file['url']):
        $html .= 'Current file attached <a href="'.$file['url'].'" target="_blank">Preview file</a>'; 
    endif;
    $html .= '<p class="description">';
        $html .= 'Upload your PDF here.';
    $html .= '</p>';
    $html .= '<input type="file" id="wp_custom_attachment" name="wp_custom_attachment" value="" size="25" />';
     
    echo $html;
 
} // end wp_custom_attachment
```

I would recommend using ACF for custom fields. There is no point to reinvent the wheel.

**Please note that those files are not registered in your Media library so you have to manualy delete files from your uploads folder.**

Comment: Do I need to create an upload folder?

Comment: All files will be stored in wp-content/uploads/current-year/current-month/

Comment: Yes, but I am not getting the any pdf, Created a new post, Uploaded pdf but still not getting it.

Comment: I have tested the code from the tutorial link and its working for posts post type. What i have notice its that you are using save_post for guideline post type when it should be save_post_guideline -  WP 3.7: save_post_{$post_type}

Comment: Clear the cache and check again, Yes, It's working. So pdf will not show in the media but will show in the month folder. correct?

Comment: Like i said consider my recomendation of using ACF even free version will be fine for you. Happy coding !

Comment: Thank you for the help. It's working. Upvote from my side